# How to write such url pattern?

Tags: php, regex

I need URL pattern for my router which would match with:

```
/page_name.html
/page_name.html/1
/page_name.html/2
....
/page_name.html/999
```

And preg_match() must put page_name into matches[1] and digit after slash into matches[2] (or empty string, index [2] must always be present!).

I need this to not match my patern:

```
/page_name.html/
/page_name.html131
```

I wrote this:

```
^\/([\w\-]+)\.html[\/]?([\d]{1,3})?$/
```

But it mathces URLs like /page_name.html123 and doesn't put anything into matches[2] if there is no digit.

Comment: This regex matches what you want: `^\/[^.]+\.html(\/\d{1,3})?$`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use this regex:

```
preg_match('~^/([\w-]+)\.html(?|/(\d{1,3})|())$~', $matches, $input);
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/qQ0eL6/1)

- `(?|...)` - Subpatterns declared within each alternative of this construct will start over from the same index. This is to make sure to always populate `$matches[2]` with something, even an empty string.